# Django - admin_media_prefix access from javascript

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-staticfiles

In the admin, I would like the *admin media url* to be accessible from any javascript.
I already have it included in the request context.
But in order to be able to access it from an included javascript,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "{{ ADMIN_MEDIA_URL }}";
</script>
```

Do I have to put something like that in a base template or is there a cleaner way to do that ?

Comment: i have printed my media url in template as: `console.log("{{MEDIA_URL}}")` it works! then what's wrong with this admin media? may be its not in context properly?

Comment: That's because it's retrieved from the template engine. But I'm talking about getting this value from a separate js file.

Comment: If you put it in a separate js file you won't be able to dynamically set it with the template variable ADMIN_MEDIA_URL. I believe the way you did it is the default Django way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media (static) files are not interpreted by django in any way. On a production site python code might not even have an access to that files, as they are probably served by the frontend webserever. So you have a crazy option: use something like server side includes (SSI) to embed the variable content into choosen media files by *somehow* parsing the config file.

Better idea would be to have same admin media prefix scheme for every site, flexible per-site config file for your webserver of choice, where admin media files would be served from some known location:

```
location ^~ /media/ {
    root        /.../django-$django_ver/contrib/admin/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can provide a somewhat "evil" solution: since Django 1.4 `django.contrib.admin` is using `django.contrib.staticfiles` for everything static. Since Admin's Javascript is using `missing-admin-media-prefix` if it's not found, we can do a redirect, e.g. in Apache:

```
RewriteRule ^/missing-admin-media-prefix/(.*)$ /static/admin/$1 [L,R=301]
```

(if your `STATIC_URL` is set to `/static`, of course)

This method is especially nice if you hack around stuff in Admin a lot and also don't want to clutter your templates with global Javascript variable declarations.